# Reapprove layout with butterknife

Tags: android, layout, butterknife

I have a BaseActivity that contains this structure:

```
<!-- activity_base -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        layout="@layout/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my `BaseActivity` I'm controlling the `BottomNavigationView`. And I created several Activities where I would like to take advantage of the include content and load only the contents of that activity.
Today the project is using `butterknife` Java. And the project is getting giant because it is replicating the top structure of the `BaseActivity` for each sub activity. I would like to refactor (in the best and quickest possible way) the project so that there is only one
`activity_base.xml` and other activities control only its content (`content.xml`).
I saw something using `ViewStub` and another describing `<merge>` but I did not understand how to apply the concepts easily in the project since many use activity and fragment, my project is only with activities.

Comment: Cant you use the exactly same layout.xml for all activities?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely happy with this solution but I ended up with something like that working on a similar case:

**base_activity.xml**

```
<...>
  ..... Whatever you want at the top
<.../>


<!--  Container where your child Activity layout will be inflated -->
<FrameLayout
    layout="@+id/child_activity_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<...>
  ..... Whatever you want at the bottom
<.../>
```

**BaseActivity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    ViewGroup parent = findViewById(R.id.child_activity_container);
    View childView = inflateChildLayout(LayoutInflater.from(this), parent);
    // The child Activity can have no layout (for some reason)
    if (childView != null) {
        parent.addView(childView);
    }

    ButterKnife.bind(BaseActivity.this);

    // ... the rest of your onCreate

}

@Nullable
protected abstract View inflateChildLayout(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent);
```

**ChildActivity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(...); // Already managed by the base Activity so we don't need it
}

@Override
protected View inflateChildLayout(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_child, parent, false);
}
```

The idea is the `BaseActivity` manage the inflation of the child layout inside its own layout and manage the call to ButterKnife. As the parent and the child are in reality the same instance (as ChildActivity extends BaseActivity) ButterKnife both the parent and the child Views. That's why it's called after the call to `inflateChildLayout`

Comment: I didn't know about ViewSub so probably you can use it to improve the code above.